# Selecting two fields from two different tables with different names

Tags: mysql

^ How can I do that?

**CODE**

```
SELECT Officer FROM fines WHERE Name=... 
UNION 
SELECT id FROM houses WHERE Owner=...
```

Tried this but it would return only the first part.

I this query to return something like this: Officer's name and house ID.

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is `JOIN`, not `UNION`

Comment: What is the structure of your tables?

Comment: Well, you could give me an example, I know only basics.

Comment: @LăpădatRăzvan check out Gordon's answer

Comment: Can you provide an example? With a sample from both tables and result you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `union`, which is returning a single column.  This column will sometimes be `officer` and it will sometimes be `id`.

I think you want a join;

```
SELECT f.Officer, h.id
FROM fines f join
     houses h
     on -- join condition goes here
WHERE Owner=...
```

I don't know what the join condition is, perhaps something on the owner of the house.

Comment: Well, let me explain you again, because I can't tell you the condition ... I want to return two 'variables', house ID and Officer Name when WHERE is equal with the inputted string... I hope you understood. If not, I give up. :D